# Python macOS Mojave cv2.waitKey doesn't work

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macos-mojave

Since I updated my mac to Mojave, my python script doesn't work properly.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    key=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    print(key)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I run this Script on my mac and press *q*, I will just get the *mac beep sound* and nothing happens. On Ubuntu instead it prints 113 and closes the window. Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Update your cv2 package, maybe.

Comment: what versions are do you have installed?